# Fetch data tak a long time when I refresh the Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using useEffect hook to fetch data from the films API,When I fetch data on my page then first time data load on the page when we refresh the page the data take a long time to reload and in my console messages of rendering and re-rendering does not display after refreshing the page.
MY App.js File

```
import { SearchHistory } from '../SearchHistory/SearchHistory';
import './App.css';
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { SearchResult } from '../SearchResults/SearchResult';

export default function App() {
  const comanyName='Trio Solutions'
  const [terms,setTerms]=useState(['new hope','empire']);
  const [films,setFilms]=useState([])
  function addTerm(term){

    setTerms([term, ...terms])
  }
        useEffect(()=>
        {
          console.log('Initial render start')
          fetchData('films');
        },[])
  
async function fetchData(type){
  let url = `https://swapi.dev/api/${type}`;
  let resp = await fetch(url);
  if(!resp.ok) throw new Error(resp.statusText);
  let data = await resp.json();
  setFilms(data.results);
  
}
 
  return (
   
    <div className="App"  >
     
        <Header cname={comanyName} />
        <Searchbar term={terms[0]} addTerm={addTerm}/>
        <main className='content'>
        <SearchHistory terms={terms}/>
        <SearchResult films={films}/>
      
        </main>
     
    </div>
   
  );
}
```

//My searchResults File

```
import './SearchResult.css'
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export const SearchResult = (props) => {
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log('initial render of films only')
}
  ,[])
useEffect(()=>{console.log('initial re-render and films only')},[props.films])

  return (
    <ul className='results'>
      {props.films.map(film=>(<li key={film.episode_id}>{film.title}</li>))}

    </ul>
  )
}
```

Please find out how can I fix the problem that every time when I refresh the browser page every time my console show all messages of rendering and re-rendering of films and data should not take a long time to reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fix the error using following solutions :
App.Js file :

1. declare fetchData() above the addTerm() function.
   2  useEffect should have a dependency array [films].
2. props?.films?.map... this should declare like this and maybe like this :
   props.films && props.films.map.
3. Maybe this API is sending a large object in response that's why your page keep reloading.